# Changing Double Integral Order

Tags: multivariable-calculus

So I understand that we can do $$\int_{0}^{1}  \int_{0}^{x}  f(x,y)\ dy\ dx=
\int_{0}^{1}  \int_{y}^{1}  f(x,y)\ dx\ dy $$. This evaluates to a number for a given function $f(x,y)$.

I'm trying to flip the integral order for this expression:
$$g(y) = \int_{0}^{1}  \int_{0}^{y}  f(u,v)\ dv\ du$$, which for a given $f(u,v)$, is an expression containing $y$. I can't seem to get it to work. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: As you wrote it and without further information, the upper limit $\;y\;$ in the innermost integral works as a constant...

Comment: If $y$ acts as a constant, does that mean there is no way to flip the order of integration?

Comment: The other way around: if that is a constant then it can be flipped without problem as the integration domain is simply a rectangle with sides parallels to the axis.

Comment: @DonAntonio Understood. Thank you!